# ID3 tag extraction

Tags: mp3, id3

How can i extract the information embedded in ID3 tag from mp3 file in windows and android environment?

Comment: Did my answer end up being correct?  If so can you please approve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [id3lib](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/) for a c/c++ library and [jid3lib](http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/) for a library in Java, which you will need for Android.

For .NET development I would recommend using TagLib#. To reference and use the TagLib# library you need to run the following command in the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio.

```
PM> Install-Package taglib
```

The NuGet distribution of taglib-sharp can be found at http://nuget.org/packages/taglib. The official source code repository is at https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp.